# Sql query limiting number of groups

Tags: sql

Hi i have a table with the following fields 'Site Code' 'Date' 'Hour' 'Quantity' and i want in a query to take all the inputed data of the last week. But there can be more than one inputs for one date so i will have to group according to Date first and then order those groups in DESC and take the last 7. The query i am using however does not work as it should because it orders the groups but in days with multiple inputs i am getting only 1 of them. 
the query is:

```
SELECT `Quantity` , `Hour` , `Date`
FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM `13_trans_coffee`
      WHERE `Site Code` =103713
      GROUP BY `Date`
      ORDER BY `Date` DESC
     )days
LIMIT 0 , 7
```

sample data

```
site code  date            hour    quantity
103713     5/12/2011 0:00  21      10
103713     5/12/2011 0:00  20      11
103713     4/12/2011 0:00  14      10
103713     6/12/2011 0:00  20      10
103713     8/12/2011 0:00  23      10
```

notice i have 2 inputs for day 5/12/2011 but the results of the query are

```
quantity   hour    date
10         23      8/12/2011 0:00
10         20      6/12/2011 0:00
11         20      5/12/2011 0:00
10         14      4/12/2011 0:00
```

one input is missing.

Comment: The LIMIT approach will give more than 1 week worth of data if there are any days without data.  Is that actually what you want?

Comment: yes i assume there wont be any.

Comment: Your sample data has a gap ;)  But, if you're not expecting gaps, can you just use `Date >= CURDATE() - 7` instead?

Comment: I guess i could do that as a final resort.

Comment: It's not really a final resort.  If you have that knowledge of the data, then it's actually an optimisation and would be my preference - I would expect that to be fastest.  If you don't have that knowledge, then I'd expect `Date >= (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM (SELECT LIMIT 0,7))` to be fastest.  This is because using a range operator is nearly always faster than using IN, JOIN, etc; It's just more index friendly to query a range once than specific values 7 times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below one should work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `13_trans_coffee`
WHERE  `Site Code` =103713 AND `Date` 
IN
(
SELECT `Date`
FROM `13_trans_coffee`
WHERE `Site Code` =103713
GROUP BY `Date`
ORDER BY `Date` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 7
) Z;
```

Comment: You need the `site code` where clause in both the inner and outer queries.

Comment: Why? I am filtering out all the records in the inner query for that particular site code. We don't require site code in the outer query.

Comment: At present you are saying "only for dates that site 103713 has data".  But what if every other site in the system *also* has data for those dates?  You'll pull the records for all of those sites too, as the outer clause is *only* restricting the selection by date and not site.

Comment: Okay I agree with you partially.. But the inner query doesn't give any other results except for site code 103713 right?

Comment: The inner query gives the top 7 dates for which site 103713 has any data.  The outer query must then only show data for only those dates, and only site 103713.  It's the last 4 words of that sentence that your query does not currently do.

Comment: I still don't get you Dems.. All we need is top 7 (date)groups of  data for site code 103713. Even though we add your filter condition for the outer query or not it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Dems has a point but yea, your query looks good, i didnt think about it, it should be like SELECT * FROM 13_trans_coffee WHERE `Site Code` =103713 `Date` IN ( SELECT `Date` FROM 13_trans_coffee WHERE `Site Code` =103713 GROUP BY `Date` ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 0 , 7 ) Z
i tried it and its not supported by my version for some reason, do you know what version supports queries with in.

Comment: @Venk - Imagine data for 2 sites.  One has data for dates (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and the other has data for dates (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).  Your query is then in two parts.  The inner query establishes the 7 most recent dates for one specific site; in our case that could be (3,4,5,6,7,8,9).  The outer query then selects data for those dates.  But on dates (3,4,5,6,7) *both* sites have data, and your query will return that data for *both* sites.  Although the inner query has the filter by site, that *does not* filter the outer query.  To get what the op asks for you need the where clause in *both* places.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying me Dems.. I got you... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last 7 populated dates...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `13_trans_coffee`
WHERE
  `Site Code` = 103713
  AND `Date` >= (SELECT MIN(`Date`) FROM (SELECT `Date` FROM `13_trans_coffee` WHERE `Site Code` = 103713 ORDER BY `DATE` DESC LIMIT 0,7))
ORDER BY
  `Date` DESC
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `13_trans_coffee`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `Site Code`, `Date` FROM `13_trans_coffee` WHERE `Site Code` = 103713 GROUP BY `Site Code`, `Date` ORDER BY `DATE` DESC LIMIT 0,7)  AS filter
  ON  filter.`Site Code` = `13_trans_coffee`.`Site Code`
  AND filter.`Date`      = `13_trans_coffee`.`Date`
ORDER BY
  `Date` DESC
```

If you want the last 7 days (plus today)...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `13_trans_coffee`
WHERE
  `Site Code` = 103713
  AND `Date` >= CURDATE() - 7
ORDER BY
  `Date` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `GROUP BY` incorrectly.  Omit it totally for what you want.

Whenever you `GROUP BY` by `Foo` only unique `Foo`s appear in the output which in your case happens to be the Date

Answer (score 0):

**This is exactly correct from a SQL standpoint.**  You even mentioned in your query you want to `GROUP BY Date` when you group by a field it finds all instances of that field and generalizes it / summarizes it.

In your sample data you group by with a value of 5/12/2011 (twice).  You cannot expect to get two entries for that date with a `group by date` only.

You will need to group by `date` and `hour` if you want to get two entries for `5/12`, the combination of both the time and the date will give you two entries (for 5/12).  Please note that if you have the same hours/minutes between both tuples that this would result in one tuple as well.  If you want multiple instances of a date, then you do not need to group by at all.

The only other thing I can think of is why are the times of your field all set to 0:00?  If you had actual values down to the second/minute you might be able to get away with multiple tuples using a group by of date.

Comment: @Dems - That is exactly why I answered the question, please read my answer.

Comment: If i group by date and hour i will get the extra input but then i will be counting that date twise, i want to count 7 days. They are set to 0 in order to be groupable as the same group, meaning 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tag what DBMS you are using?  I'm thinking analytic functions, but I don't know what syntax you need.